# Dynamic state update in mobx react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I want to have a function that accepts only the state declared in mobx. I currently have this code.

```
class DialogStore {
    status: boolean = false;
    title: string = '';
    content: string = '';
    btnText: string = ''; 
    icon: JSX.Element | string = '';
    type: 'success' | 'error' = 'success';

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    toggle(status: boolean) {
        this.status = status
    }

    success(content: string) {
        this.type = 'success';
        this.status = true;
        this.content = content;
    }

    error(content: string) {
        this.type = 'error';
        this.status = true;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

I want to add a dynamic function like this:

```
update(payload: TypeOfState) {
    Object.keys(payload).forEach(property => {
        this[property] = payload[property];
    })
}
```

I tried to place `any` as my payload type but it gives me this error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DialogStore'`. I want the payload to only accept the state I declared at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have single function instead of `toggle`, `success` and `error`?

Would something like this work for your case?

```
class DialogStore {
  // ...

  update(payload: StateToUpdate) {
    Object.keys(payload).forEach((property) => {
      this[property] = payload[property];
    });
  }
}

type StateToUpdate = Partial<Pick<DialogStore, 'status' | 'type' | 'content'>>
```

To avoid TS error you could disable flag `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` altogether in your `tsconfig.json` or use some typecasting:

```
    Object.keys(payload).forEach((property) => {
      (this as any)[property] = payload[property as keyof StateToUpdate];
    });
```

I think there is no easy way to mitigate this type of error in TS right now, I might be wrong though.

Comment: You understood it right it produces an error ```Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DialogStore'```. Probably because it is a class and calling ```this[property]``` where ```property``` could also mean a function like success() or error()

Comment: I've updated my answer a little bit. I am not quite sure how to make such function with complete type safety though

Comment: I solved it using ```(this as any)[property] = (payload as any)[property]```. Then I created a type for state then casted it on payload. I realized putting any on this does give any disadvantage for typescript since the only thing that I want to be typed is the payload prop